# Export rmi on virtual machine

Tags: java, spring, jvm, rmi, hosts

I want to export java.rmi on virtual machine,

```
<bean id="entityRmiServiceExporter" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
<property name="serviceName" value="entityService"/>
<property name="service" ref="entityServiceImpl"/>
<property name="serviceInterface" value="IEntityService"/>
<property name="registryPort" value="1099"/>

<property name="registryHost" value="127.0.0.1"/>
```

i get connection refused to 127.0.0.1

hosts file :

> 127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
>
> 10.0.2.15 compname

is this problem with vm ?

Comment: if i do not write the registryHost it exports to ip address but i can not connect to that ip in client

Answer (score 0):

Change the networking mode of the virtual machine to "bridged" so it will be in the same network as the host. Java RMI was not designed to work with NAT, so you'll have trouble with the default networking mode.

After that, change `registryHost` to the IP address of the VM, 127.0.0.1 can only be accessed from within the machine.

(There are other ways to make this work but this is the easiest to explain)

Comment: thanks,have another problem now, server started but client cannot connect to registryHost=ip

Comment: Does the VM have an IP address that can be reached from the host?

Comment: So all communication happens inside the VM, there's no outside traffic at all? Then the fact you're using a VM is irrelevant and unrelated to any problem you are having.

Comment: yes, all in vm. then why the same code works on host machine but does not in vm